# Image Views in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios4

```
 [self.scrollView addSubview:[self.minkyImageView initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey_1.png"]]];
```

I am adding an image to a scrollview like the above. My `minkyImageView` is attached to the scrollview on the UI builder and i also have the outlet connected. However when run the code i dont see the image unless i set the image on the UI builder. I dont want to do this since i want to change images every time a scroll takes place so therefore i need to customize it via code. So what am i doing wrong? I am writing this method in viewdidload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not call init more than one time. And `init` should always called in conjunction (i.e. on the same line) with `alloc`.

why don't you use `self.minkyImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey_1.png"];`

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have outlet connected, the minkyImageView is already initialized. What i'd do:

```
[self.minkyImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"monkey_1.png"]];
```

and if your image view is already inside scroll view - you don't need to call `addSubview:` on it.